# For any set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$, if for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^p$ that $E(x)$ is measurable, does $E$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

The definition $E(x)=\left\{y\big|y\in\mathbb{R}^q\land <x,y>\in E\right\}$ is all the points that in E while $x$ is selected.

And furthermore, $E$'s projection in $\mathbb{R}^p$ is also an measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^p$.

In fubini it is said that if $E$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$, then for almost every where $x\in\mathbb{R}^p$ that $E(x)$ is measurable can be derived.

So I would further like to know if the reverse is true??

And if it is, may I have the prove, thanks a lot!

Comment: You posted a  similar question earlier today and it was closed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It's the reverse of what you are saying

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm asking that if $A$ is measurable and for all $x\in A$ that $E(x)$ is also measurable. Then if I can conclude that $E$ is measurable. It is a reverse of your comment

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In your example, I can only say that $\{0\}$ is measurable, but $E(0)=A$ is not measurable, it does not satisfy the condition and totally not what I was asking

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy please read the second line that "$E$'s projection in $\mathbb{R}^p$ is also an measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^p$", which totally conflict with your $A$ is not measurable comment

Comment: If $f: \mathbb R^{p} \to \mathbb R^{p}$ is a bijection which is not measurable then the graph of $f$ gives  a counter-example. [Consider the intersection of this set with $\mathbb R^{p} \times C$].